# Assigning integer values to an enumeration within a struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, enums

I am learning enums and structs right now and have a case I cannot solve. If I have a basic struct and define an employee, I see I can do the following..

I have the employee added to the first item, but how can I have the user input an integer and then have that integer be assigned to Low, Medium or High using the enum nested within the struct? Thanks!

```
struct add {

    char employee[255];
    enum EmployeeLevel {Low = 0, Medium, High};
};

struct add EMP[10]; //Global variable to add employees using the add struct

printf("Please enter employee name\n");
scanf("%s", EMP[0].employee); //Assigns the user input to the name of the first employee
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be off, but you could do something like this:

```
enum EmployeeLevel {Low = 0, Medium, High};  //declare the enum outside the struct


struct add {

    char employee[255];
    enum EmployeeLevel level;                //create a variable of type EmployeeLevel inside the struct
};

struct add EMP[10]; //Global variable to add employees using the add struct

printf("Please enter employee name\n");
scanf("%s", EMP[0].employee); //Assigns the user input to the name of the first employee
scanf("%d", EMP[0].level); //Assings a level to the corresponding employee
```

Answer (score 0):

This just cannot work. scanf would need to know the size of the item that it is reading in bytes. However, C doesn't define that size for an enum.

Create a temporary variable of type int, scanf into that variable, then assign it to the enum. And obviously be aware that if you change your enum, you will be in trouble because the meaning of a number would change. And obviously be aware that using a very short name like Low, Medium, High for an enum will get you into trouble if your program gets to any reasonable size. Use something like eEmployeeLevel_Low instead.